# Prove that Chebyshev's inequality is not sharp

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

**Problem:** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mu)$ be a probability space and $X$ a random variable on this space. Prove that if $0<E[X^2]<\infty$, then
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{a^2P(\vert X\vert\geq a)}{E[X^2]}=0.$$

**My Attempt:** Observe that
$$a^2P(\vert X\vert\geq a)=\int_\Omega a^2\cdot\mathbf1_{\{\vert X\vert\geq a\}}\,d\mu\leq\int_{\left\{\vert X\vert^2\geq a^2\right\}}\vert X\vert^2\,d\mu.$$
Therefore, it suffices to prove that
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{\left\{\vert X\vert^2\geq a^2\right\}}\vert X\vert^2\,d\mu=0.$$
To see this, take a sequence of positive real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with $a_n^2\nearrow\infty$. Since the sets $\{\vert X\vert^2\geq a_n^2\}$ and $\{\vert X\vert^2<a_n^2\}$ are disjoint and their union is $\Omega$, it follows from the properties of the Lebesgue integral that for all $n\in\mathbb N$ we have
$$\int_{\left\{\vert X\vert^2\geq a_n^2\right\}}\vert X\vert^2\,d\mu=\int_\Omega\vert X\vert^2\,d\mu-\int_{\left\{\vert X\vert^2<a_n^2\right\}}\vert X\vert^2\,d\mu.$$
Now consider the sequence of functions defined by $X_n=\vert X\vert^2\cdot\mathbf1_{\{\vert X\vert^2<a_n^2\}}$. Then $X_n\to \vert X\vert^2$ almost everywhere and $\vert X_n\vert\leq\vert X\vert^2$ also almost everywhere. Therefore, the dominated convergence theorem implies that
$$\int_\Omega\vert X\vert^2\,d\mu-\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\left\{\vert X\vert^2<a_n^2\right\}}\vert X\vert^2\,d\mu=0.$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\left\{\vert X\vert^2\geq a_n^2\right\}}\vert X\vert^2\,d\mu=0.$$
It follows that
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{\left\{\vert X\vert^2\geq a^2\right\}}\vert X\vert^2\,d\mu=0,$$
and hence
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{a^2P(\vert X\vert\geq a)}{E[X^2]}=0.$$

---

Could anyone give me some feedback on my proof above? Any comments are much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's correct (well, I haven't checked for typos, just the general argument), but in my opinion too drawn out. Why wouldn't it be sufficient to say that by the dominated convergence theorem $\lvert X\rvert^2\cdot \chi_{\lVert X\rVert \geqslant a} \to 0$ in $L^1$ as $a \to \infty$?